# Firefox - MasterKey == Plain-text passwords?

Tags: firefox, security

I can recall that somewhere (maybe even at on of the SE sites) I have read something like "if Master Key is not used and passwords are stored separately, Firefox saves them in plain-text (whereas when Master Key is used, it is also used to actually encrypt/decrypt the stored password blobs).

So is it correct, that Firefox usage (lets say as of year 2023 with the Ubuntu LTS shipped version) without Master Password leads to unsafe local config, that is vulnerable to disk analysis for unencrypted passwords). I mean, it is pretty common scenario, when people are sharing one PC, they sometimes are too lazy to bother with creating and maintaining separate OS logins).

Comment: Using any sort of password safe without *additional* credentials (not derived from the device or user account) is unsafe.

Comment: Possible relevant: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/109073/how-does-firefox-encrypt-passwords-without-selecting-master-password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit unclear what "stored separately" is supposed to mean, but FFox does not save them plain-text. The login data is stored in `logins.json`, [encrypted](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-firefox-securely-saves-passwords).

Here's an example from my `logins.json`, no Master Key configured:

```
{"id":3,"hostname":"https://www.examplesite.com","httpRealm":null,"formSubmitURL":"https://www.examplesite.com","usernameField":"usernameemail","passwordField":"password","encryptedUsername":"MEIEEPgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEwFAYIKoZIhvcNAwcECBvOEj0DFigIBBhKSDTP1Z3UDUW/qEShVEOiR5nimB9/Q9U=","encryptedPassword":"MDoEEPgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEwFAYIKoZIhvcNAwcECChBK6lbakZ/BBA+tCo0X0yExqOM+J53H1Zy","guid":"{749d06f4-4280-44ba-a366-2f2509e8dc0a}","encType":1,"timeCreated":1630176396074,"timeLastUsed":1678223464142,"timePasswordChanged":1630176396074,"timesUsed":2}
```

If the system has multiple users, the login data is stored in each user's profile.